# Getting ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when passing gensim.word2vec to feed_dict

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, seq2seq

I am creating a seq2seq model with tensorflow(not Keras) and the input /output are sentences. Something like a chatbot or translator.

But when I run

```py
for epoch in range(total_epoch):
    _, loss = sess.run([optimizer, cost],
                       feed_dict={enc_input: input_batch,
                                  dec_input: output_batch,
                                  targets: target_batch})
```

I get

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

`input_batch`/`output_batch` are arrays of `gensim.word2vec.wv.vectors` of sentences.
I tried other things as input as well but I still get the same error.
For target it is an array of array (each internal array is a list of number mapped to the word for the sentence).

The target_batch that gets the error, looks like this:

`[[297, 242, 430, 451, 507, 507, 505, 506, 506, 506, 506, 506], [297, 242, 430, 451, 507, 507, 505, 506, 506, 506, 506, 506], ...]`

and for `input_batch`/`output_batch` I have tried everything.

I use `gensim` `word2vec` and for `inputbatch.append(input_data)` `input_data` is made for each sentence using `gensim` `word2vec` as following:

```py
model=Word2Vec(input_sentence.split(), size=5, window=10, min_count=1, workers=4, sg=1)
```

I have done everything, from saving it to bin and retrieving it to using `model.wv.vectors`. I get that error for all 3 of `enc_input`, `dec_input` and  `targets`

`enc_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, n_input])`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to match the shape of your vector tensor target batch with the keys in your feed dictionary, `enc_input, dec_input, targets`.  From the [documentation for tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) Session.py:

> The optional feed_dict argument allows the caller to override the
>   value of tensors in the graph. Each key in feed_dict can be one of the
>   following types: 
>       If the key is a tf.Tensor, the value may be a Python scalar, string, list, or numpy ndarray that can be converted to the same dtype
>   as that tensor. Additionally, if the key is a tf.placeholder, the
>   shape of the value will be checked for compatibility with the
>   placeholder.

The placeholder has to have a shape compatible with the input tensor.  It might be easier to use a numpy array for your target batch, and use that to set the dimensions of your placeholder, like this:

```
import numpy as np

target_batch = np.array([[297, 242, 430, 451, 507, 507, 505, 506, 506, 506, 506, 506], [297, 242, 430, 451, 507, 507, 505, 506, 506, 506, 506, 506], ...]) #full list of lists

enc_input = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape=target_batch.shape, name=None)
```

I can't test that without more information, but hope that helps.